# upload multiply file and remove button

Tags: jquery

So i have code that allow user to click on icon and than to choose file to upload. each time they click on the icon new INPUT field added with type "file" and the name is the same - "file[]" (array).

what I'm trying to do is to allow uploading multiply files. each time use choose file i want to print it's name and add "remove" button next to it.

how can i do that?

this is what i have now:
(hide = display:none )

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <img class="uploadFileImg" alt="" src="images/photoIconOn.png"> <br /><br/>
    <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='file-field hide' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" />

</form>
```

js:

```
$(".uploadFileImg").on('click',function(){
   $(".file-field").trigger('click'); 

    var new_field = $("<input type='file[]' class='form-control file-field hide'>");
    $(this).closest('form').append(new_field);     

});
```

Remove files:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.clear_file',function() {
        $(this).closest('form').find('input.file-field').val("")
        $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html("");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery and Bootstrap, we'll stick with that.

So we're going to need two input groups:

1. The default one with an add option
2. The hidden one with a remove option

This is what the HTML will look like:

```
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="file">Upload Image</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input id="file" class="form-control" type="file" name="file[]" accept="image/*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button class="btn btn-default add" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- START FILE UPLOAD TEMPLATE -->
    <div id="upload-template" class="form-group hide">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
            <input id="file" class="form-control" type="file" name="file[]" accept="image/*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button class="btn btn-default remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END FILE UPLOAD TEMPLATE -->
</form>
```

Then we simply clone the hidden template group when someone clicks the `+` button, and remove it when someone clicks the `-` button:

```
$('#form')
.on('click', '.add', function () {
    var $template = $('#upload-template');
    var $clone    = $template.clone().removeClass('hide').removeAttr('id').insertBefore($template);

    $clone.find('[name="file[]"]');
}).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.form-group');

    $row.find('[name="file[]"]');

    $row.remove();
});
```

You can see a working example on JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/divspace/pwepeez1/

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your time! just 1 thing - in your code you display the input field, I would like that the "+" icon will open the browser dialog and when i choose file the code just print it's name with the "remove" (-) icon next to it.

Comment: It may be easier to use an existing library in this case. Checkout [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) or [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). They handle multiple files and customizing them is easy enough.